# What is the difference between void QSqlQuery::clear() and void QSqlQuery::finish() in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qsqlquery

The documentation is kind of vague on the subject:

From [void QSqlQuery::clear()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#clear):

> Clears the result set and releases any resources held by the query.
>   Sets the query state to inactive. You should rarely if ever need to
>   call this function.

From [void QSqlQuery::finish()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#finish):

> Instruct the database driver that no more data will be fetched from
>   this query until it is re-executed. There is normally no need to call
>   this function, but it may be helpful in order to free resources such
>   as locks or cursors if you intend to re-use the query at a later time.
>
> Sets the query to inactive. Bound values retain their values.

Does one imply the other? Which resources will be freed in each case? Why would I use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the idea is rather clear and functions does not imply each other. First one does clear everything:

> Clears the result set and releases any resources held by the query

After that you won't be able to get any information on this query, while the second one just marks a query as inactive (well, it just "says" that it's empty) and prepares the query to be ready for being

1. re-executed
2. cleared

> Bound values retain their values

It means that at least some data is still accessible after the execution of the `finish()`.

If you don't want to create another `QSqlQuery` object and want to execute a completely different query, then you may use `clear()` and not be afraid of any memory leaks or something else. But if you are planning to execute the same query later, for example with another set of bound values, you may use `finish()`. It will also release some driver's internal resources (as it's said in the documentation).

Comment: Thanks! Is this something you know or something you "think" is the answer? If you "know" I will mark it as the correct one :-)

Comment: @LennartRolland - the source of the information is the official documentation, so I can say "I KNOW" :-)